# Windows 7 failed on installation at 98%

Tags: windows-7, installation, crash

I hope you can help me after umpteen failed attempts to load Windows 7 on an ASUS P5WD2 premium board and dual core intel 3.4Ghz 2Gig Ram  processor ran the beta versions  beautifully, the mini dump info is as folllows, fails at approx 98 % load on install same every time no matter what i do, have tried disabling ethernet driver no difference:

Dump File         : 121810-30718-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 18/12/2010 16:28:32
Bug Check String  : IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000000a
Parameter 1       : 0x00000000
Parameter 2       : 0x000000ff
Parameter 3       : 0x00000000
Parameter 4       : 0x82878550
Caused By Driver  : ndis.sys
Caused By Address : ndis.sys+35023
File Description  : NDIS 6.20 driver
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
Processor         : 32-bit
Computer Name     :
Full Path         : H:\Windows\Minidump\121810-30718-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 2
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7600

======================

Please help!

**Additional Notes from Answer:**

first i did have the release candidate 64 bit working fine until it ran out of time , I then tried dubious copies of 64 bit W7 which a friend guaranteed worked on his computer but the same thing happened again and again, failure , the computer unexpectedly closed down that is what it says , after up dating registry values I now have a legit copy of 32 bit W7 failure at this same point and the mini dump report of the blue screen is as described, it fails at exactly the same point in the same way every time , I have tried with no partitions on a good 500gb West Digit caviar , 2 gb Ram and an intel 3.6 ghz dual core( not the extreme  ie with out hyper threading).

used a program me to extract mini dump info also in the crash report it highlights

file names : ndis.sys +35023
             ntoskrnl.exe +54c11
             yk62(times)86sys 12b6b

the last two do not appear in the mini dump report

I do not know where to go from here, it suggests it is a driver or some  drivers that are at fault ?
But I am not sure how to solve this one am a novice at this level.

Comment: We need some more history in this issue, is it a clean install of W7? Has the installation ever booted without the error?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar problem complained about [here](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7hardware/thread/05785887-52c1-4a98-b280-24b6413d323e). Hope this is helpful.